# Handling 2 file inputs

Tags: php, html

I would like to create 2 file inputs and upload both of them to the server.
I did it already with 1 file in that way:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="image/*" step="1">
```

And the php script something like that:

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";

else
{
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
        echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    else
    {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
        "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    }
}
?>
```

But now when I want to have 2 inputs, I duplicate the html code:

```
<input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" accept="image/*" step="1">
<input type="file" name="file2" id="file2" accept="image/*" step="1">
```

And I have no idea what I need to change or duplicate in my php script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$_FILES["file"]
```

references the uploaded file from

```
<input ... name="file">
```

so the first level of `$_FILES` are the `name`s of the HTML file inputs. You can either duplicate your code and change every `$_FILES['file']` to `$_FILES['file1']` (and `$_FILES['file2']` in the duplicated code), or you loop through the `$_FILES` array - although this could be a *security risk*, as one could easily trick your script into storing more than two files.

Answer (score 0):

With the html you have you have two $_FILES multidimensional arrays one referenced as 
`$_FILES['file1'][]` 
and the other as 
`$_FILES['file2'][]`.

doing a var_dump($_FILES) in your code to will help interrogate what information is being submitted.

You may have to duplicate this block, I've shown code based on your example set to file1 or use a foreach loop such as

```
foreach( $_FILES as $file ) {
   //reference each value using $file as follows.
   $file['name'];
   $file['size'];
}
```